# How to Import Vuejs Component Dynamically Only If Component File Exists

Tags: javascript, wordpress, vue.js, vuejs2

First off I'd like to start by saying I'm new to Vuejs but and I'm having to learn it as a beginner while also having need for more advanced Vuejs use cases that I haven't gotten to learning just yet.

I'm working on a WordPress plugin (not sure if this is useful info) that has an addon.

I've created the component inside the Addon plugin (let's call it Plugin B) and have that component loading inside the base plugin, (Let's call it Plugin A, ***Plugin A will always exist, it's Plugin B that might not always exist***)

When I run the npm scripts to compile the files everything works fine, Plugin A loads the component that's located in Plugin B, and that component can make calls to Vuestore and interact with Plugin A just fine.

The issue arises when of course Plugin B is **not present**. Since Plugin B is an "Add-on", there would, of course, be cases where it doesn't exist, *in those cases the browser console and vue reports that it can't find the component*. So I need Plugin A to **only try to load the Vue component if Plugin B exists.**

My first thought was to put an if statement around the import statement:

```
if(something){
import myComponent from '../../../../plugin-b/vue/src/vue-elements/my-component.vue' 
}
```

But this is not possible in JS and I get a console error saying `import` cannot be inside an if statement. This still doesn't seem like it would work and I think if it did I'd need to be loading a .js file and not .vue (I do have a .js file being compiled from Plugin B's my-component.vue, I'm just not sure what to do with it)

---

During my reading, I've stumbled across extending components but I'm not sure if that's the right way to go in addition to not getting a good grasp on how to go about it.

Below is a simplified version of how the workflow currently works:

**Plugin A:**  (This component lives in **plugin-a/vue/src/vue-elements/settings-panel.vue**)

```
   <template>
     <div>
      <div>Some other markup</div>
      <div>Some other markup</div>
      <div>Some other markup</div>
    
    # Ideally it would be better if I can have some base markup being rendered here
    # And v-if the 'my-component' exists, then load its markup instead of the base markup
     <my-component></my-component>
     </div>
   </template>
            
        <script>
            
            // Doesn't work when plugin-b doesn't exist...of course
            // But plugin-b is an add-on, there would be cases where it doesn't exist
            import myComponent from '../../../../plugin-b/vue/src/vue-elements/my-component.vue' 
            
            module.exports = {
                    name: 'settings-view',
                    data: function () {
                        return {
                           // I have some data here
                        }
                    },
                    // Other properties
                    components: {
                     myComponent
                   }
            }
 </script>
```

**Plugin B:** (This component lives in **plugin-b/vue/src/vue-elements/my-component.vue**)

```
<template>
  <div>
    // Markup for component
  </div>
 </template>

<script>
       
        
        module.exports = {
                name: 'my-component',
                data: function () {
                    return {
                       // I have some data here
                    }
                }
          // Other properties
        }
    </script>
```

Any help in achieving what I'm trying to do is appreciated

Comment: I have been using Vue, but haven't done what you are describing, so not posting this as an answer, but take a look at this in docs.  Possibly it will help. [Dynamic & Async Components](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#Async-Components)

Comment: it sounds like you are compiling your vue code. that's problematic.    you can dynamically do it in the browser.  However, why not have both plugins and have some configuration which says whether it is active or not?

Comment: @KeithNicholas One plugin is an add-on meaning, Plugin A is free (Lite version) and Plugin B is paid (Pro add-on), purchasing Plugin B will add more functionality to Plugin A and "open up" some UI elements(replace) 

As per the WordPress guidelines, if you're going to have a feature locked in the free version of a plugin, the logic for that feature should exist in the Pro version. So the Free/Lite version can have basic HTML elements with no functionality, and when the Pro plugin is installed it can replace those static elements with dynamic Vue code